# Load a library from memory on Linux with Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, linux, memory, shared-libraries, ctypes

I'm trying to load a library from memory rather than using a file using ctypes and CDLL.

Here is what I have tried so far with no success.

**Reading a file into memory for testing purposes only**

```
file_bytes = open('./lib.so', 'rb').read()
lib = CDLL(file_bytes)
```

This results in the following error message:

```
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name,mode)
ValueError: embedded null byte
```

I then tried using the io library:

```
io_bytes = io.BytesIO(file_bytes)
lib = CDLL(io_bytes)
```

and I get this error:

```
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name,mode)
TypeError: expected str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not _io.BytesIO
```

I looked into PathLike objects, and I'm not sure if there is a way to reference my memory data with it.

Comment: The reason is irrelevant and this is not an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
def load_shared_lib(lib_bytes):
    temp_lib = '/tmp/temp_lib'
    with open(temp_lib, 'wb') as temp_file:
        temp_file.write(lib_bytes)
        lib = CDLL(temp_lib)
    os.remove(temp_lib)
    return lib
```